# How to cast an entity to a list using facade method

Tags: java, persistence

I'm trying add and remove object from that list using the method "listarEntregaKitRegistro", but .xhtml that supose to show the list wont display anything in the screen.

Kit is an entity class from my database, kitFacade is method that allow you to get a list about some entity in this case kit, kitFacade is also generated by netbeans as a session bean from entity classes, actually kitFacade.findAll() is working well and retrieve all the elements from that list, but i need to get them with some exceptions.

```
public List<Kit> listarEntregaKitRegistro(){
 for (int i=0; i<=kitFacade.findAll().size(); i=i+1){    
    if (kit.getEstadoKit()=="Activo"){
        kitFacade.findAll().add(i, kit);
        }
    else {
          kitFacade.findAll().remove(i);
          }
    }
    return kitFacade.findAll();
}
```

Exception thrown by glassfish server 4.1.1:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.entity.Kit cannot be cast to 
java.util.List
at com.controller.KitController.paraEntregar(KitController.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
```

Comment: Plase edit your question to provide a [mcve]. At least include the `com.controller.KitController.paraEntregar()` source code where you are doing a wrong cast.

Answer (score 1):

I did't know where you are casting `Kit` to `List`. but you are doing wrong String comparison. May be in your some other function you are casting your object into list. Here is the code with some modification.

```
public List<Kit> listarEntregaKitRegistro(){
 List<Kit> list = kitFacade.findAll();
 for (int i=0; i<=list.size(); i++){    
    if (kit.getEstadoKit().equals("Activo")){ // compare String by Equals method
       list.add(i, kit);
     }else{
      list.remove(i);
       }
    }
    return list;
}
```